# PHP count replacement

Tags: php

I have some code that works fine on servers running below PHP 7, but on PHP 7 I get a warning that I need to get rid of. I need to fix the code to get rid of the warning, I can not just hide the warnings.

My issue is with the count() function. Here is the warning I am getting and the little bit of code it is referring to. The array has the possibility of having many elements, some with values and others with blank values. It is also possible that the array will be empty. I assume that when the array is empty, that is when the warning is triggered. So I am looking for a way to tell if the array has 1 or more elements, with and without blank values. As long as there is one key then the if statement should be true.

```
PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

      $tb_operator_meta_json = get_post_meta($tableid, 'tb_operator_meta', true);
      $tb_operator_meta = json_decode($tb_operator_meta_json, true);
      $tb_operator_meta = wp_unslash($tb_operator_meta);

      if (count($tb_operator_meta) > 0 && $tb_operator_meta != null) {
```

I don't know why this was marked as a duplicate. If you read my post it is clearly not the same as the other post.

Comment: Use `var_dump` to see what you're actually dealing with. It's not a (normal) array, otherwise you wouldn't get this error, even if it's empty or contains empty values.

Comment: The error is because `get_post_meta($tableid, 'tb_operator_meta', true)` is returning a value and not an array as you can check in [the documentation][1] you can set the third parameter to false to get an array.

You can change your comparation to something like 

    if ($tb_operator_meta > 0 && $tb_operator_meta != null) 

Or change the call of your function
`get_post_meta($tableid, 'tb_operator_meta', false)`

Comment: GolezTrol, this in no way is a duplicate of that post, but whatever. Chopi, I know that get_post_meta is returning a string. It returns a JSON string to be exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [PHP 7.2.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php#refsect1-function.count-changelog)

> count() will now yield a warning on invalid countable
>   types passed to the array_or_countable parameter.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

check the array `is_array()` before counting.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I feel like someone is just downvoting to downvote.

Answer (score 3):

check if it is an array or not null.

use `is_array($var);`

or

use `(!empty($var))`

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote.