# PHP 7.4 - Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array

Tags: php, count, php-7, php-7.4, countable

I just upgraded my **PHP Version from 5.6 to 7.4. I used count()** function in my page, example:

```
$watch_server_count  = count($watch_server);
if ($watch_server_count > 0) {
    foreach ($watch_server->table as $key=> $watch_server_rows) {

    }
}
```

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in...

Comment: Check what `$watch_server` contains.

Comment: `$watch_server` is an object, not an array, hence the `$watch_server->...`. Did you mean `$watch_server_count  = count($watch_server->table);` ? This would make sense since you are iterating this property

Comment: object(ShinoDB)#6137 (3) { ["error"]=> NULL ["filename"]=> string(187) "OK^https://ok.ru/videoembed/963440478908 Vidbom^https://www.vidbm.com/embed-qx0qzffbptht.html Vevio^https://vev.io/embed/k4rdekk1q2o1/ Vidshare^https://vidshare.tv/embed-l8w79d88qq1v.html" ["table"]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "OK" [1]=> string(37) "https://ok.ru/videoembed/963440478908" } } }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable error in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542767/count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-countable-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP count replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855519/php-count-replacement)

Comment: In PHP 7.2 and above versions count() function just accepting array as an argument. Check this topic [Upgrade to PHP 7.2 caused error in function counting form input array
](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/upgrade-to-php-72-caused-error-in-function-counting-form-input-array)

Comment: Please add all information to your answer instead of linking to external ressources

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way. **is_countable**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-countable.php

```
if ( is_countable($watch_server->table) ) {
    foreach ($watch_server->table as $key=> $watch_server_rows) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mehmet, welcome to Stackoverflow. If you post an answer, please check whether there are already other answers covering the same code. In this case, there's another answer from Redy S. Additionally, your answer might be wrong, as not all objects that implement the `Countable` interface provide the neccessary methods to iterate

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 7.1, you can use `is_iterable` before performing `foreach`.

> (PHP 7 >= 7.1.0)
>   is_iterable — Verify that the contents of a variable is an iterable value

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php

So the code will look like this:

```
if ( is_iterable($watch_server->table) ) {
    foreach ($watch_server->table as $key=> $watch_server_rows) {
        //
    }
}
```